# Failed to add dependency on mongod.target[Service], ignoring: Invalid argument

Tags: mongodb, service, rocket.chat

When I install Rocket.Chat server on CentOS 7, I have created `rocketchat.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Rocket.Chat server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target 
mongod.target[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/Rocket.Chat/main.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=rocketchat
User=root
Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat 
ROOT_URL=http://www.leavenotrace.cn PORT=3000
[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I pressed on command:

```
systemctl start rocketchat
systemctl status rocketchat
```

Show below error:

```
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:3] Failed to add dependency on mongod.target[Service], ignoring: Invalid argument
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'Type' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:5] Unknown lvalue 'ExecStart' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'Restart' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:7] Unknown lvalue 'StandardOutput' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:8] Unknown lvalue 'StandardError' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:9] Unknown lvalue 'SyslogIdentifier' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:10] Unknown lvalue 'User' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:11] Unknown lvalue 'Environment' in section 'Unit'
Apr 18 11:50:13 VM_56_252_centos systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service:12] Invalid section header '[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target'
```

Comment: Your problem is the two missing newlines in the `rocketchat.service` file, right before `[Service]` and right before `WantedBy=`.

Answer (score 1):

before:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/rocketchat.service
```

It will show these error.

After:

```
nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat.service
```

in it write:

```
  [Unit]
  Description=The Rocket.Chat server
  After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target nginx.target mongod.target
  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/Rocket.Chat/main.js
  StandardOutput=syslog
  StandardError=syslog
  SyslogIdentifier=rocketchat
  User=root
  Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat ROOT_URL=http://www.leavenotrace.cn:3000/ PORT=3000
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is OK.

Comment: The location of the file is not the issue, whether it’s in `/etc` or in `/usr/lib`. Just cut your answer down to the point: there are two missing newlines in the OP’s `rocketchat.service` file.

Comment: By the way, this is the OP.